# Nuget package produces corrupt web.config file (assemblyBinding section)

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

**edit: solved the problem already! See my answer below.**

I have a strange problem with a nuget package I have created.
I already have created several nuget packages and never had this problem before, but now suddenly when installing the new package, it will produce a invalid web.config file.

The nuspec file is almost exactly the same than in some other (working) projects. I add the install script and some special contents and set the dependencies in the metadata section:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>Kooco.com Ltd</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <description>Server-Project Template for use with the Kooco.Framework</description>
    <releaseNotes>Pre-Alpha Release</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>Maxima Kooco WebProjects</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0" />
      <dependency id="AutoMapper" version="6.0" />
      <dependency id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.2" />
      <dependency id="Kooco.Framework" version="$version$" />
    </dependencies>
    <references>

    </references>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="install.ps1" target="tools" />
    <file src="NugetOverwriteContents\**\*.*" target="tools\OverwriteContents" />
    <file src="NugetNoOverwriteContents\**\*.*" target="tools\NugetNoOverwriteContents" />
  </files>
</package>
```

The dependencies are exactly the same like in other (working) packages.

But for some reason, when installing the package, nuget will produce the following web.config section, which leads to errors in the application, because of non-closing tags:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" /><assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" /><assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

before installing the nuget package it was:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" /><assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

I do NO custom config transformation.
I have a install script, but this script is not the problem, I also tried installing without the install script and have the same issue.

The destination project is an empty ASP.Net web application, where I was using the "Empty" template with "MVC" and "WebAPI" activated.

My nuget package manager version is 3.5.0.1484. Automatic updates enabled.
I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. My system is Windows 10.

Someone have an idea what could cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Someone have an idea what could cause this issue?

I created a nuget package with your nuspec file, but not include the part of  `<files>... </files>`, then install it to the ASP.Net MVC project. It works fine. So I have no direct solution for this issue without more detail information, I could provide you some troubleshootings:

First, please exclude man-made modification on the web.config. Because the default binding info should be like below:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

But in your web.config, duplicate `bindingRedirect` under the package Newtonsoft.Json:

```
<dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" /><assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" /><assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly>
```

You can create a new blank ASP.Net MVC project to check this.

Second, we can modify the web.config through a [web.config.transform file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/source-and-config-file-transformations) or by using an XML document transform (XDT).

The web.config.transform file contains the same as a web.config file and it will be applied to the web.config file when you install the NuGet package.
 And XDTs are more powerful and can do more complicated modifications to the web.config file, such as inserting or removing existing elements. So please double check if any config transformation file included by your package with the wildcard "*". You can try to exclude those files in your package to check if this issue still persist.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:
the problem was, that in some of my projects the web.config file had the build action set to "Content" and it seems the nuget package builder automatically generated a web.config transform out of it then.
Changing the build action to "None" solved the problem.

It btw. helped a lot to use the "NuGet Package Explorer" tool, which allows you to see the contents of a nuget package created, where I saw the automatically created "web.config.transform" file then.